# How to reload a model in Sidekiq worker when it tries to reference the model too fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When the user clicks on a button in the Rails UI, it triggers a worker that looks for a record created by the user. For example, when the user creates a "schedule" to start at a predefined time (sometimes immediately), a worker gets kicked off and tries to find that schedule, sometimes failing with a "cannot find record" error.

```
class TestWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym

    def perform(schedule_id)
        begin
            schedule = ScheduledTest.find(schedule_id)
        rescue
            sleep 5 # schedule was just created so needs time to update in db
            TestWorker.perform_async(schedule_id)
            return
        end
    end
end
```

This is the current workaround. When the worker starts too fast and can't find the schedule, I now have it to call itself again, and then it works. However, it seems like there should be a way to "reload" the model rather than restarting the entire worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the :after_commit callback, so the job will not be created until the database transaction has committed.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to take advantage of the callback cycle provided by `ActiveRecord`.

`after_create` comes to mind:https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create

So in your `ScheduleTest` model:

```
after_create :trigger_worker

def trigger_worker
  TestWorker.perform(id)
end
```

Alternatively, you could call `perform_async(id)` to dump it in a queue